# Xamarin Forms overriding Android switch property using Effects

Tags: xamarin.forms

I would like to override the On/Off text of a switch using an Effect rather than a custom renderer.

In Android, I have the following code:

```
        protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Control is Android.Widget.Switch control)
            {
                control.TextOn = "Yes";
                control.TextOff = "No";
            }
        }
```

OnAttached executes as expected but 'Control' is not an Android.Widget.Switch control but of a related type, e.g. 'android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat'. How can I make the code recognize that it should update the text in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the result like following effect?

[image]

You can achieve it like following code.

```
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("MyCompany")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(SwitchDemo.Droid.ClickEffect), nameof(SwitchDemo.Droid.ClickEffect))]
namespace SwitchDemo.Droid
{
  public  class ClickEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            // throw new NotImplementedException();

                if (Control is SwitchCompat control)
                {
                control.ShowText = true;
                    control.TextOn = "Yes";
                    control.TextOff = "No";
                }

        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is PCL code.
`ClickEffect.cs`

```
  public  class ClickEffect: RoutingEffect
    {
        public ClickEffect() : base($"MyCompany.{nameof(ClickEffect)}")
        {

        }
    }
```

Use it in xaml.

```
        <Switch>
            <Switch.Effects>
                <local:ClickEffect/>
            </Switch.Effects>
        </Switch>
```

Comment: Thank you. Will the SwitchCompat control work for the most recent versions of Android or only for older versions?

Comment: SwitchCompat control work for the most recent versions of Android

Comment: @ccdmfc If the reply is helpful, please don’t forget to mark this answer(click the ☑️ at the top right corner of this answer ), it will help others who have similar issues.